# Set color of divs with same class?

Tags: css, html

I have 2 divs on my site, they have the class X. Each of the divs is in another div, with a different class each, A and B for example.

```
<div class="A">
    <div id="div1" class="X">something</div>
</div>

<div class="B">
    <div id="div2" class="X">something else</div>
</div>
```

Now the content of those divs should be colored green. How can I say that both divs should be green using only one css class definition? Something like:

```
.A .B > .X {
    color: green;
}
```

I hope you guys know what I mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to separate the rules (can't compound the parent like you are):

```
.A > .X,
.B > .X {
    color: green;
}
```

The above stating "When an element has class `A` or `B` and the direct child has class `X`, assign the text color to `green`."

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
.A .X , .B .X
{
color:Green;
}
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F5kFv/)**